# how to convert ifstream to istringstream

Tags: c++, fstream, istringstream

I have a function that reads through an `istringstream` and does some operations on it so ... I am trying to read in a file using `fstream` and convert the `fstream` object to an `istringstream` in order to pass it to my function. I don't know how to do this. Any help would be much appreciated. I am still pretty much a beginner so please keep it simple if you can.

```
string inputFile(argv[1]);    
ifstream inFile(inputFile.c_str());    
istringstream is;

is >> inFile.rdbuf(); //*******This is wrong and is what I'm having trouble with

function(is);
```

Comment: Looks like a good opportunity to learn polymorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is `std::istream_iterator`:

```
std::string myString ( std::istream_iterator(inputFile) , std::istream_iterator() ) ;
std::istringstream is ( myString ) ;
```

This creates a string with the contents of inputFile by using a begin iterator (`std::istream_iterator(inputFile)`) and an end iterator (`std::istream_iterator()`). It then creates an istringstream from that string.

This solves your immediate problem, but there is almost certainly a better way to do what you are trying to do. For example:

- Pass an `istream` instead of an `istringstream` (because then you don't have to copy it).
- Change your algorithm to not need an `istringstream`.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot convert a `std::ifstream` directly to a `std::istringstream`.

However, your function that uses a `std::istringstream` should simply be rewritten to use a `std::istream` instead, so that it can be used both with `std::istringstream` and `std::ifstream`.

If you really want to take a `std::ifstream`, and get a `std::istringstream`, you should use std::istreambuf_iterator to construct a temporary `std::string`, which is the only parameter type that a `std::istringstream` accepts. But that's bad design. Use a `std::istream`, and pass the `std::ifstream` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Stringstream cant take from a file, it can only take from a string and give out to a string. 
Make a string to hold the information from the file using getline/etc then feed that into the stringstream. Also make sure to clear the stringstream after using it ex. Stringstreamname.clear().

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you need to do, but going beyond your direct question, I will bet that you want to read in a line at at time, even if you don't know that yet.

In C++, if you read in anything that does not fit, the input gets "stuck."
For example, suppose input is mistakenly:

4 4x

The x is a typo.

If you read it:

```
int a,b;
cin >> a >> b;
```

a and b will both be 4.  But the next time you read, it will fail because of the x.

Instead, read in each line into a string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream f("input.dat");
    string line;

    getline(f, line);
    istringstream s(line);
    int a,b;
    s >> a >> b;
    cout << (a + b) << '\n';
}
```

And of course, as others have said, you should write your code in terms of reading from istream, independent of where it is coming from.